# Outside of use in microchips and FPGAs does SHA-3 have a lookup table?

Tags: sha-3

Is SHA-3 normally used with a LUT or hash table?

Comment: Again, put some context in the question. You can quote the text by preceeding each paragraph with the `>` markdown operator. I know you're reading a lot about these things, but we all learn these the different ways, so some context are often needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Outside of use in microchips and FPGAs does SHA-3 have a lookup table?

(I'm answering the title and the question; the question might be interpreted as 'do you use SHA-3 to implement a LUT or hash table?')

Well, some implementations have the per-round constant in the Iota transform stored as a look up table (however, those are not hard to compute, so some implementations do compute them on the fly).

Other than that, the transforms that SHA-3 does internally are regular enough that we generally don't find a look up table useful.

Comment: Thank you, this will do